# Outbound DDOS Attacks Being Run from Our Server

Tags: centos, security, ddos

We run a mail server (postfix/dovecot/centos 6.4). The hardware is based on a supermicro chasis with IPMI features.

It also runs a web interface for accesisng mails(Apache web server )

Recently our DC said that we are sending outbound DDOS attacks which touched upto 1.3Gbps as per their saying. They nulled the IP. After our request they re activated the IP again.

Now we are monitoring the server regulerly and seeing abnormal outbound traffcis at a avearge rate of 2mbps we dont sent that much emails) with peaks of upto 30mbps after each 30minutes period.(as per the data of New Relic Monitor)

The provider said that we might be running DDOS reflection attacks. The server logins are safe and authentication log says nothing abnormal

We dont have any DNS server running. Also NTP is running in client mode and it is secured.

nettop, iptraffic,nethogs show everything normal, only transmitted and recieved traffic summary in ifconfig says about the large amount of data sent.

Also we disabled NTP client on our IPMI as i read that supermicro IPMI is vulnerable to NTP reflection DDOS.

AT this point I am clueless and seeking help from experts here. Helps will be appreciated!

Comment: I'd definitely look at running `tcpdump` during one of the "busy" periods.  That would give a first idea of what *kind* of traffic it was, which has got to be a first step in understanding how you're producing it - if you are.

Comment: I tried to do, so and unfortunately, I cant find anything except some normal SMTP connections and my own SSH Connections. If i again run tcpdump and paste the o/p here can you help me??

Comment: I'm sure someone will be able to take a useful look at it - but it won't help unless you do it during one of the apparent attacks (ie, when your `ifconfig` statistics are rapidly increasing).

Comment: Obviosly I will do that, I exactly know when ifconfig traffics increase, tried running nettop. iptraffic etc etc but they show normal traffic of about 100-200kbps when actually the traffic is around 30mbps!!

Comment: Uhh, you can't always disable NTP on the IPMI cards.  Sure the UI might let you do that, but don't actually rely on that to do anything.  You'd need to actually check this isn't vulnerable.

Comment: You need to install some logging/monitoring/graphing tools so you can look at what has happened after the fact, otherwise you'll have to sit at the console waiting for the problem. A simple bash script recording the output of 'ps auxf' , 'top' , 'netstat -tap' etc to a log file running every 5 minutes can be enough. In any case if your DC is sure you were sending out DoS then you can consider your server compromised unless proven otherwise, so "server logins are safe" etc are out of the window. Also what port/service was your server sending traffic to? you can block it as temp stop gag measure

Comment: Well, I installed New Relic RPM remote monitoring service for that purpose. It gives a output of spike of upto 30Mbps after each 30minutes. If i see top/netstat etc at the peak time. I dont see anything else except normal processes like amavisd, dovecot/ssh,smtp etc. We can see which port is sending DDos as its not detectable from local machine.

Comment: devicenull, how to do that, I use a supermicro IPMI Firmware Revision : 01.07 Firmware Build Time : 2013-05-30, How to check this for vulnerability??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your IPMI Firmware to a latest version. It looks like it's not your OS but vulnerable IPMI card.

You didn't tell us which model of IPMI/Chasis it is, but on [the list of latest Super Micro firmwares](http://www.supermicro.com/support/bios/firmware0.aspx) there's no version 1.07, so it has to be newer one.